# Find the total of whole roots of the equation below

Tags: quadratics

For how many real values of the number does the equation $x^2+ax+6a=0$ have only integer roots?

Putting it in wolfram it shows $18$ roots but I couldn't demonstrate

Perfect square: $\Delta = a^2-24a = k^2$?

Real Roots: $\Delta = a^2-24a \geq 0 \implies a \leq 0 \vee a \geq 24$